# How to update image url index in firebase databse android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update images `url` index after deleting one image into Firebase database. I deleted index 1 image and I want to update index 2 as index 1!! Please Help me.

Here my Firebase database storing multiple images
[image: Here my firebase database storing multiple images]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to do an extra operation since you can change the structure of your `url` node a little bit, so you don't have to do an extra write. So I recommend you change that node to:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  +--- Blog
       |
       +--- blogId
             |
             +--- // blog details
             |
             +--- url
                  |
                  +--- "https://firebasestorage...": true
                  |
                  +--- "https://firebasestorage...": true
```

In this case, when you are deleting a url frm the `url` node, no other operation is needed.

**Edit:** If you want to store the `url` of the image as a key, the encoded version is required, since you need to strip the illegal characters. As @FrankvanPuffelen's mentioned in his comment, using a hashcode is also common practice and then use the full URL as the value.

Comment: Im storing as images under url only but in firebase databse its showing 0: imageurl of first image , 1: image url of second image like that .

Comment: I see your database, that's why I recommended you to change it a little bit so don't need to to anything once you are deleting an url, right?

Comment: how can I change the structure of url node . I didn't got from you.

Comment: As in the structure from my answer. Instead of having `0: "https://firebasestorage..."`, you should have `"https://firebasestorage...": true`, right?

Comment: Im not send sending like 0, 1 …… its only showing like . im sending imageurls through arraylist  and its default storing like 0, 1....

Comment: Yes, you're right. When you are using arrays, this is the bahaviour. Try to store maps, in which the key is the link and the value is the boolean `true`. Is ok now?

Comment: @AlexMamo the download URLs won't be usable as keys, since they contain characters that aren't allowed. You'll want to use an encoded version of the URL as the key (I typically just strips the illegal characters, but a hashcode is also common) and then use the full URL as the value.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just wanted to show to the OP visually how the `url` node should look like. Yes, encoded version of the URL is required. Thanks again for your comment! Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks . I need to try using hasp map

Comment: After using map its showing error {https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapplication-97483.appspot.com/o/images%2FIMG-20180722-WA0006.jpg?alt=media&token=5544d165-4020-4a75-90e0-cc7cf4aae96c=true}

Comment: Check the permissions in your Firebase Console. Set them for testing purposes to true.